# How to host drupal in wpn-xm, nginx

Tags: php, nginx, wpn-xm

Recently I downloaded the WPN-XM full installer and try to further develop my drupal website, because WPN-Xm performs faster than other development stacks in Microsoft Windows.  But in drupal, only homepage is visible, all other pages show 404 error. My site using the clean url feature in drupal. How could I successfully host drupal website with WPN-XM's nginx web server?

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451795/nginx-rewriting-with-drupal-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Installation Instructions for Drupal 7 
with "Clean URLs" and local domain for WPN-XM**

1. https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.42.zip
2. extract into `/www` folder

   - drupal brings its own folder: `drupal-7.42`, rename it to `drupal7`
3. open in browser: http://localhost/drupal7/install.php
4. select "standard"
5. enable PHP Extension "gd"

   - `php.ini`: `extension=php_gd2.dll`
6. create database with Adminer

   - http://localhost/tools/adminer/adminer.php
   - in case you need to change root pw, use `reset-db-pw.bat` in the server root
   - create table "test"
   - create new user and pw
7. use the "database", "user" and "pw"
8. configure site
9. finally Drupal is installed: http://localhost/drupal7/

**Enable local VHost - http://drupal7.dev/**

1. copy the drupal7.conf from `domains-disabled` to `domains-enabled` folder

   - i've updated the config once more. you find the updated file over here: https://github.com/WPN-XM/software/blob/master/nginx/config/conf/domains-disabled/drupal7.conf
2. edit the file and check that you have:

   - `root         www/drupal7;`
   - `server_name  drupal7.dev;`
3. then add vhost with SCP

   - right-click tray, "ManageHosts"
   - click add enter `127.0.0.1` with `drupal7.dev` + "ok"
   - click main "ok"
4. restart nginx
5. finally, open http://drupal7.dev/

**Enabling Clean URLs**

1. open http://drupal7.dev/
2. login

   - after login the URL is: http://drupal7.dev/?q=node
3. To enable clean urls go to "Configuration > Clean-Urls" or directly to

   - http://drupal7.dev/admin/config/search/clean-urls
   - http://drupal7.dev/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls
4. enable checkbox "enable clean urls", then submit
5. finally, open http://drupal7.dev/admin/content

In the end you get a vhost `drupal7.dev` with clean URLs - served from `C:\<server>\www\drupal7`.